# Passing a JavaScript property to variable - Node / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I feel like I'm making a stupid mistake, but I'm suffering the "too noob to know what to search for" syndrome.

I have a Node/Express app in which I'm trying to make a call to a mySQL DB and return user information. I'm then trying to pass the user email to an Infusionsoft API.

I can successfully pass a static email, and the process works but when I'm trying to save the value to a variable, it stops working.

Here's the code:

Route:

```
 router.get('/subscribers/:id', function(req, res, next) {

  var userID = req.params.id;
  subscriber.subscriberIndividual(userID, function(err, userInfo){
    var userEmail = userInfo.Email;
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }   
      billing.infusionsoftDetails(userEmail, function(err, userBilling){
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
          }
        console.log(userInfo);
        console.log(userBilling);
        res.render('subscribers/edit', {
        'userInfo' : userInfo, 
        'userBilling' : userBilling
      });  
    });
  });
```

Controller:

```
infusionsoftDetails: function(userEmail, cb)
    {
        infusionsoft.subscriberDetails(userEmail).then(function(rows){
        cb(null, rows);
        })
        .catch(function(err)
        {
        cb(err);
        });
    }

}
```

Model:

```
subscriberDetails: function(userEmail)
    {
        return infusionAPI.RecurringOrderWithContacts
        .where(
            RecurringOrderWithContact.Email, userEmail)
        .select(
            RecurringOrderWithContact.ContactId,
            RecurringOrderWithContact.Email, 
            RecurringOrderWithContact.FirstName,
            RecurringOrderWithContact.LastName,
            RecurringOrderWithContact.Phone1,
            RecurringOrderWithContact.Status,
            RecurringOrderWithContact.PaidThruDate,
            RecurringOrderWithContact.NextBillDate,
            RecurringOrderWithContact.BillingAmt,
            RecurringOrderWithContact.StartDate,
            RecurringOrderWithContact.EndDate
            )
        .take(1)
        .toArray()
        .then()
    }


};
```

Again, if I swap out the userEmail from the .where call to a static email address, it works just fine. With the variable, nothing. Help?

Comment: Does userInfo.Email return what you are expecting ?

Comment: I'd suggest you insert a `console.log(userEmail);` in each of your functions and see what it's initial value is and/or where it's getting lost.  I don't see an obvious mistake.

Comment: Hmm, good question. I just added console.log(userInfo.email); and it came back as undefined

Comment: Logging userInfo works. Logging userInfo.email or userEmail returned undefined. 

This is what the returned object looks like: 

`[ { username: 'randomuser',
    id: '4f9c4d15-3e7c-4f11-9d82-e6e0f6dabcde',
    email: 'randomuser@gmail.com',
    active: 1,
    last_login: Fri Jul 24 2015 12:53:58 GMT-0400 (EDT),
    created: Sat Apr 28 2012 20:03:33 GMT-0400 (EDT) } ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to [Mariano Iglesias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/763522/mariano-iglesias). Returned object is an array. userInfo[0].email correctly passes the email back to the API.